# rename sequence in other schema with same currval

Tags: sql, sequence, rename, alter, nextval

I need to rename bunch of sequences in another schema.

RENAME old_seq to new_seq doesnt work.

Tried:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE old_seq RENAME TO new_seq;
```

but it gives me error

```
ORA-02286: no options specified for ALTER SEQUENCE
```

I do not wish to mention all the options that i had mentioned earlier while creating the sequence, since they need to be same. Only the name needs to be changed.

Comment: Which DB are you using??

Answer (score 3):

If you are not the owner of that sequence, You can use following steps:-

```
SELECT CURVAL FROM old_seq;
```

This will give you the value of Current_Sequence.

Now Drop this sequence using

```
DROP SEQUENCE old_seq;
```

And Create new Sequence with same name. Using

```
CREATE SEQUENCE old_seq;
```

And then alter that with this:-

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_example INCREMET BY <CURVAL FROM OLD VALUE>;
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @ankit is quite in line with what's needed to fix this issue but it presents a few problems and typos which I'm fixing in this answer. I hope it'd be useful.

First, you have to select the current value for the *old_seq*:

```
SELECT old_seq.CURRVAL FROM dual;
```

If you get an **ORA-08002** error that's because you need to ask for the NEXTVAL first in order to initialize the sequence. Just do:

```
SELECT old_seq.NEXTVAL FROM dual;
```

and then ask for CURRVAL again.

Now that you have the current value, just drop the old sequence by using

```
DROP SEQUENCE old_seq;
```

and create the new_seq with the name you want by using

```
CREATE SEQUENCE new_seq START WITH <CURRVAL FROM old_seq>;
```

If you use `INCREMENT` instead of `START WITH`, you should take into account that the increment would apply to every request for a value from the sequence. You would have to create the sequence and then reset the increment to 1. Using `START WITH` avoids that issue.

Comment: Unfortunately 'START WITH' takes a constant, so your solution can only be done manually, not via script.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename it straight out:

```
rename old_sequence to new_sequence;
```

It would say table renamed but you can ignore it. Your sequence will be renamed.

Try it.

Comment: no. As mentioned, the owner of the sequence is difference. It doesnt allow direct renaming of the sequence.